# node js create server and connect

Tags: javascript, node.js

Look at the following code :

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    //Code block A


    socket.on('connect', function() {
        //Code block B
    })

    socket.on('data' , function (data){
           //Code C     

    });

});
```

Is there a chance code block A will be executed and code block B won't and vice versa?
And if so, in what cases?

For counter example : Once code A has been executed Code C can run multiply time, without Code A ever running again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, providing you call `.listen()`, I think you'll find that You get an order of:

```
(Client connects) // "connect" event fires
   |
   v 
  [A]--*-----.  // This is the Socket's "connect" event firing.
       |     |  // B and C are bound to their respective events.
       |     |
       |     |
      [B] <--.  // Binds handler to "connection" event, but 
       |        // connection event fires instantly
       |
      [C] <--.  // "data" event is fired
             |
(Client sends data)
```

Furthermore, *A* will never begin execution after *B* as the socket reference that *B* is bound to is located within the scope of closure *A*.

@Joe, I also think this sounds interview'y, but what the hey!

Comment: I don't understand you scheme. From what i understand code B will run every time code A will run. True?

Comment: Indeed, the function passed into [net.createServer](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) is registered as the handler for the server's 'connect' event.

Comment: See my edited post for a little more clarity, refixing the diagram as I write this.

Answer (score 1):

This smells a bit like an interview-type question but...

1) Neither A or B will run because there's no `server.listen` to make it start listening.

2) <strike>If you call `.listen` then A will run (if the .listen was successful) but B will not run until a client connects to the server.</strike> On a connection, A will run, then B (assuming a successful connection).

Comment: Not an interview, just curious.

Comment: And you are wrong.When you start to listen code A will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If code in block B is executed, then code in block A must have been executed.

Comment: Code c can run multiply times after code A has been executed once.